# making AnchorPane resizeable based on its parent

Tags: java, javafx, responsiveness

I have a column with 3 rows. Each row includes an image . this column is a child of a `GridPane` . as you can see in the following FXML :

```xml
<GridPane GridPane.columnIndex="1">
    <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="7.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" />
      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="30.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="30.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
       <ImageView fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="29.0" onMousePressed="#addNewUser" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
            <image>
              <Image url="@/views/add.png" />
            </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="29.0" onMousePressed="#removeUser" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <image>
              <Image url="@/views/remove.png" />
            </image>
      </ImageView>
      <ImageView fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="29.0" onMousePressed="#editUser" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
            <image>
              <Image url="@/views/edit.png" />
            </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

based on my understanding `GridPane` has fixed size and won't be changed accordingly to the size of the parent . (Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong). Thus I need to wrap them with `AnchorPane` which can be resized . so I added it and I got the following :

```xml
        <children>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="1000.0" prefWidth="900.0" style="-fx-background-color:red" >
                <GridPane GridPane.columnIndex="1">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="7.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="0.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="30.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="30.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="29.0" onMousePressed="#addNewUser" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@/views/add.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="29.0" onMousePressed="#removeUser" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@/views/remove.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="29.0" onMousePressed="#editUser" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@/views/edit.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                    </children>
                </GridPane>
            </AnchorPane>
        </children>
    </GridPane>
</children>
```

And now the result is that all those 3 are sticking to each other and no sign of resizing at all. For the sake of debugging 
I've set the background of my `AnchorPane` to red and it shows that the height and and it's width are as they should be but still all those images are sticking to each other. Any idea how can I fix this ?

Comment: Your `AnchorPane` tag has no `children` tag inside. It should be structured as `<AnchorPane><children><GridPane> ... </GridPane></children></AnchorPane>`.

Comment: @DVarga I've added the children tag but yet the same out put

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `AnchorPane` takes all the available place, but its children do not. That's the default behavior, you can change it by explicitly setting all anchors to zero.

```
<GridPane GridPane.columnIndex="1"
          AnchorPane.topAnchor="0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0"
          AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0">
```

Likewise, if you don't want your table to stretch vertically, you can set only right and left anchors.

```
<GridPane GridPane.columnIndex="1" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0">
```

Comment: Worked , Thanks ;) but my main question is still there . That , how can make that responsive to the changes happen in the main window that the app is running in :)

Comment: What do you mean? As long as this AnchorPane is your topmost container, it will stretch when the main window is resized.

Comment: oh i see , in fact I have two GridPanes which are nested into each other . In other words , the GridPane I have given the source up here is nested in another GridPane . Assuming that should I apply the AnchorPane for the parent GridPane or both ? :D

Comment: The problem is that GridPane resizes its columns and rows to their preferred size. The easiest workaround is to put the GridPane into a resizeable component, but it's an ugly solution and it gets worse if you have multiple GridPanes - because you need to do that for each one of them. In your case you need an AnchorPane for both GridPanes.

Comment: Alternatively, you may use the column and row constraints. This way you won't need that AnchorPane at all. Take a look at the "Row/Column Sizing" paragraph here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html